# Unable to Align Layers in Photoshop Properly with CS2

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment, layers

#### Cannot Align Semi-Transparent Items?

Windows Vista, Photoshop CS2.

Steps to repeat:

1. Create new document
2. Fill a circle on a new layer
3. Drop opacity of filled circle to 10%
4. Create new empty layer below circle layer
5. Merge empty layer with filled circle layer
6. Select entire canvas
7. Attempt to align layers to selection
   `layer > align layers to selection > vertical centers`

I get the following error:

> Could not complete the Vertical Centers command because there are no layers to be moved.

Clearly this is **not** true, as I'm selecting the layer with the semi-translucent ball on it. Now, if you had tried this same command prior to step 5 (when the layer was at 10% opacity) it would have worked.

Is there some way around this problem? I need to move layers around that begin as transparent items, with a layer opacity at 100% where 100% of the layers opacity results in showing objects that are themselves not-very opaque.

I've confirmed on another machine that this problem doesn't exist in CS3. I may exist in earlier copies of Photoshop, but I only have access to CS2 (has the problem) and CS3 (does not have the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Can you align the layers prior to merging them? (By selecting the applicable layers together, but merging them after the align.) I know that's probably an obvious one. :(

(I just confirmed that this error occurs on my computer using Adobe Photoshop CS2.)

Answer (score 0):

i had a somewhat similar problem with cs4 in that messing with transparencies caused unexpected/illogical behavior;
now, i havent used cs2 but try this:
instead of making the layer with the object transparent, apply a layer effect of transparency;
then try to move it around or whatever is needed;
if that doesnt work, save the item as a transparency before attempting to align;
again, i am not sure these features exist in cs2, but this just sounded like a similar problem i had;